# New to NodeJS. Mongoose How to Async multiple queries?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Ok, lets say I have two Models.  Contract and CommLog.  Both work find independently but I need many CommLog to relate to each Contract.

In the ContractSchema trying async

```
ContractSchema.methods.getCommLog = function getCommLog(){

var log = false;
async.parallel([
    function(){
        CommLog.find({commType:'contract',parent:this._id},function(err,comms){
            log = comms;
        });
    }],
    function(){return log;}); 

};
```

Where I am trying to use it

```
router.get('/:code', function(req, res, next) {
Contract.findOne({accessCode:req.params.code},function(err,contract){
    if(err)
        res.send(err);

    var data;
    if(contract != null){
        var comms = contract.getCommLog();
        data = {error:false,data:contract,commlog:comms}

    }else{
        data = {error:true,message:"No Contract"}
    }
    res.json(data);
});
});
```

Where it shows var comms = contract.getCommLog();  It is never returning anything because the getCommLog() is not executing async...

I think its my misunderstanding of mongoose querying, so if you understand what I am trying to accomplish, please let me know what I am doing wrong. I have tried without async which would always return false.

Comment: Ok.. So I have managed to get it working but not by calling .getCommLog().  Instead I just did an async.parallel with the find query.  Was hoping to be able to keep the method in the model but I guess it won't work in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

The find call can return all matching results with one query, so I don't think you need async here. The reason it is not populating correctly when you call res.json(data) is because you are not waiting for the method call to finish before you fire off your server response. You would be better off nesting an additional CommLogs.find call within the Contract.find call, and only sending your response once that finishes.

//pseudo code:

```
Contract.find({}, function(err, contract) {
    if(err || !contract) {
        //return error response
    } 
    else {
        CommLogs.find({contract: contract._id}, function(err, commlogs) {
            if(err || !commlogs) {
                //return error response 2
            }
            else {
                res.json({errors: false, contract: contract, commlogs: commlogs});
            }
        });
    } 
}
```